# Invisible separator in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Trying to add space between two `TextField` which appear below one another in a `GridPane`.

I tried:

```
Separator separator1 = new Separator();
separator1.setStyle("separator");
separator1.setSkin(null);
```

with the CSS:

```
.separator{
 -fx-border-color: transparent;
 -fx-border-width: 0;
}
```

but we still see a grey line on the length of the separator. How to remove it and make the separator completely invisible?

Comment: The `style` property contains "inline css". However you assume it's a style class. Furthermore there needs to be a skin for controls. I'm pretty sure setting the skin to `null` has no effect at all. If you want to assign a style class, you need to use `node.getStyleClass().add("my-class");`

Comment: If the separator is not visible, why use one at all?  Why not just use a [Pane](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) instead configuring the min/max/pref width to whatever value you want for the space you need to take up?

Comment: what do you _really_ want to achieve?

Comment: Use Region if you want to keep (invisible) distance between nodes.

Comment: I thought "Region" like "Pane" sounded a bit huge for the simple separation I need (a bit of extra margin between two stuff!) but that worked indeed.

Comment: If you want to apply only a space between the 2 TextFields, use: gridPane.setVgap(int value) ==> gridPane.setVgap(15);